# How to manually add a datetime input element to a Django template without using forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, datetimepicker

I want to manually add date-time input elements to an HTML where needed, but as the targets should be dynamic, I cannot use forms. Is there a way to achieve this with JS? Something like this (or ways to achieve similar results):

```
$('#my-target-div').djangoDatetime()
```

Or

```
$('#my-anchor-button').djangoDatetime({target: '#my-input-element'})
```

I want to also have Django's field buttons (like calendar, date picker, ...) included.

I saw Django's built-in DateTimeShortcuts.js, but I couldn't achieve what I planned.

Comment: I don't really see why you can not use forms. You don't need to *render* the forms, you can use these to *validate* input as well. That being said, I don't really see what you want to achieve in the first place.